# Using awk to print without double quotes

Tags: awk

I would like to get the right value of the following command as a string without double quotes.

```
$ grep '^VERSION=' /etc/os-release
VERSION="20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
```

When I pipe it with the following `awk`, I don't get the desired output.

```
$ grep '^VERSION=' /etc/os-release | awk '{print $0}'
VERSION="20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
$ grep '^VERSION=' /etc/os-release | awk '{print $1}'
VERSION="20.04.3
$ grep '^VERSION=' /etc/os-release | awk '{print $2}'
LTS
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: If `lsb-release` is avialable `lsb-release -rs` or with `GNU` grep. `grep -Po '(?<=VERSION=").*(?=")' /etc/os-release`

Comment: @Jetchisel: Yes. You mean `lsb_release -rs`...

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the expected output so we're not guessing at what `the right value` might be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this single awk command:

```sh
awk -F= '$1=="VERSION" {gsub(/"/, "", $2); print $2}' /etc/os-release

20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)
```

Answer (score 3):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk 'match($0,/^VERSION="[^"]*/){print substr($0,RSTART+9,RLENGTH-9)' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, using `match` function of `awk` to match starting VERSION=" till next occurrence of `"` and then printing the matched part(to get only desired output as per OP's shown samples).

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Using GNU `grep` with PCRE regex enabled option try following.

```
grep -oP '^VERSION="\K[^"]*' Input_file
```

---

---

***3rd solution:*** Using `awk`'s capability to set different field separators and then check conditions accordingly and print values.

```
awk -F'"' '$1=="VERSION="{print $2}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that "the right value" you want output is `20.04.3`:

```
$ awk -F'[" ]' '/^VERSION=/{print $2}' file
20.04.3
```

or if it's the whole quoted string:

```
$ awk -F'"' '/^VERSION=/{print $2}' file
20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `awk` command like

```sh
awk 'match($0, /^VERSION="([^"]*)"/, m) {print m[1]}' /etc/os-release
```

Here, `^VERSION="([^"]*)"` matches `VERSION="` at the start of the string (`^`), then captures into Group 1 any zero or more chars other than `"` (with `([^"]*)`) and then matches `"`. The match is saved in `m` where `m[1]` holds the Group 1 value.

Or, sed like

```sh
sed -n '/^VERSION="\([^"]*\)".*/s//\1/p' /etc/os-release
```

See an [online test:](https://ideone.com/OhkNR8)

```sh
s='VERSION="20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)"'
awk 'match($0, /^VERSION="([^"]*)"/, m) {print m[1]}' <<< "$s"
sed -n '/^VERSION="\([^"]*\)".*/s//\1/p' <<< "$s"
```

Here, `-n` option suppresses the default line output, `/^VERSION="\([^"]*\)".*/` matches a string starting with `VERSION="`, then capturing into Group 1 any zero or more chars other than `"`, and then matching `"` and the rest of the string, and replacing the whole match with the Group 1 value. `//` means the previous regex pattern must be used. `p` only prints the result of the substition.

Both output `20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the file [/etc/os-release](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/os-release.html) conforms to a variable assignment in bash or the shell in general (POSIX), sourcing it should do the job.

```
source /etc/os-release; echo "$VERSION"
```

Using a subshell just in case one does not want the pollute the current env variables.

```
( source /etc/os-release; echo "$VERSION" )
```

---

Assigning it to a variable.

```
version=$( source /etc/os-release; echo "$VERSION" )
```

---

If the shell you're using does not conform to POSIX.

```
sh -c '. /etc/os-release; echo "$VERSION"'
```

---

See your local man page if available.

```
man 5 os-release
```